# What is the role of LLMNR, NBSS and NBNS protocols in WannaCry?

Tags: exploit, wannacry

I know that LLMNR is the "new version" of NetBIOS and both of them are basically for resolving names to IP addresses

I also know some exploits based on them, like a MiTM attack that the attacker sends a malicious response to the victim when the victim asks the IP address of a machine

But I don't understand their rules in the wannacry attack?

I have a PCAP capture file that I am assuming is doing the WannaCry attack, and In a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4jrLNuHneg) I was watching the guy says if you see a lot of llmnr in a capture its a red flag for eternal blue/wannacry

And indeed in this capture there is a LOT of LLMNR, NBSS and  NBNS packets, and NetworkMiner says it suspects the eternal blue exploit as well and points to these NBSS packets, but I cant understand the content of them

I see a lot Name Query NB WPAD, Refresh NB and registration NB

also all of the llmnr packets are standard query "a hex number" A  or something similar (like A wpad, ANY "a VM name", A isatap)

but I don't understand what they are doing?

can someone ELI5 what is their role in the attack without getting into too much detail?

I watched a lot of videos regarding this but non of them really answered this

**Basically What I'm asking is this:**

How these  protocols are used in the WannaCry attack? why there are a lot of these packets in a pcap file of a network that was attacked by WannaCry?

(I did watch a lot of videos and articles about this attack and about these protocols but i still dont get the connection!)